# Can I fill Primefaces Datatable with Dummy Data?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to fill a primefaces datatable with dummy data. Can I do this in any way like in normal HTML pages? In plain HTML, I can do this for example:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Berlin</th>
    <th>Hamburg</th>
    <th>München</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Miljöh</td>
    <td>Kiez</td>
    <td>Bierdampf</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Buletten</td>
     <td>Frikadellen</td>
     <td>Fleischpflanzerl</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to hardcode the same in an primefaces datatable (because I need this datatable only for demonstration purposes but I would like to keep its layout). Is there a way to do this with my `<p:datatable>`, without having to code a backing bean which fills it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. `p:datatable value="..."` attribute must resolve to a data source which is (recieved from) a managed bean e.g. of type `Collection` or `DataModel`.

Maybe you can somehow make up a `List` of `Maps` [hard coded in `faces-config.xml`](https://javabeat.net/lists-and-maps-as-managed-beans-in-jsf/), but how ugly is this?
Better create a managed bean with hard coded demo data.

Comment: Creating a managed bean would have taken less time than asking the question ;-)

Comment: @curr11 You are welcome - if your question is answered please mark it answered.